# creating user defined form controls in excel vba

Tags: vba

i have an excel user form with a comboBox for imputing no of pumps and the combo box contains drop down list from 1 to 30. how can i achieve creation of new form controls depending on the users selection? for instance if the user selects 5 i want to create 5 labels named pump1, pump2 to pump5 all with radio buttons for product selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a number of ways, the simplest being to, add in all 30 buttons and hide\unhide them with `Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()` subroutine. If that does not meet your needs, then will you probably want to use the `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3` reference, to add in buttons at runtime, then modify them on the same event.

Example UserForm Code

```vb
''  Corresponding UserForm has *only* a combobox called `ComboBox1` located at left=6, top=6.

''  Form-level constants
Private Const maxNumBtns            As Integer = 12
Private Const defaultComBoxNum      As Integer = 5

''  Update buttons
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim comp            As Boolean
    ''  prevent flashing
    Let Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To maxNumBtns
        With Me.Controls.Item(getBtnName(i))
            Let comp = i <= CInt(Me.ComboBox1.Value)
            ''  ensure hidden buttons are not pressed
            Let .Value = comp And .Value
            Let .Enabled = comp
            Let .Visible = comp
        End With
    Next
    Let Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

''  Set up UserForm
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i               As Integer, _
        btn             As String
    For i = 1 To maxNumBtns
        ''  add line to combobox
        Call Me.ComboBox1.AddItem(i)
        Let btn = getBtnName(i)
        ''  add button
        Call Me.Controls.Add( _
            bstrProgID:="Forms.OptionButton.1", _
            Name:=btn, _
            Visible:=True)
        ''  Format the button
        With Me.Controls(btn)
            Let .Left = 12
            Let .Top = 30 + 17 * i
            Let .Width = 70
            Let .Height = 15
            Let .Caption = "Pump #" & i
        End With
    Next i
    'note: this calls combobox1_change
    Let Me.ComboBox1.Value = defaultComBoxNum
End Sub

''  helper function to ensure naming stays the same
Private Function getBtnName(ByVal index As Integer) As String
    Let getBtnName = " opBtn" & index
End Function
```

---

If you are looking to have something like a combobox with a check box option, you should use a `listbox`. (you will not need the extensibility reference for this version)

Unfortunately, however, it is not possible to hide a listbox row, so this option requires removing all entries in the listbox when the combobox val is changed.

The methods below correspond to a useform, `useform1`, with a comboBox, `pumpComboBox`, a listBox, `pumpListBox`, and two commandButtons, `OkButton` and `CancelButton`.

```vb
Option Explicit

'' Calling code
'
'With New Userform1
'    .Show
'    If Not .IsCancelled Then
'        '...
'    End If
'End With

Private Const maxChecks     As Integer = 12
Private Const defaultChecks As Integer = 5
Private checked()           As Boolean
Private cancelled           As Boolean
Private updating            As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i                   As Integer
    ReDim checked(0 To maxChecks - 1) As Boolean

    ''  Add item to combobox
    For i = 1 To maxChecks Step 1
        Call Me.pumpComboBox.AddItem(i)
        Let checked(i - 1) = False
    Next i

    ''  format listbox
    With Me.pumpListBox
        Let .ListStyle = fmListStyleOption
        Let .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
    End With

    'note: this calls pumpComboBox_change
    Let Me.pumpComboBox.value = defaultChecks
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        Let cancelled = True
        Call OnCancel
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub pumpComboBox_Change()
    Dim i                   As Integer

    ''  prevent flashing
    Let Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ''  make sure values are not cleared when changing number of options
    Let updating = True
    Call Me.pumpListBox.Clear
    For i = 1 To Me.pumpComboBox.value
        Call Me.pumpListBox.AddItem("Pump #" & i)
        Let Me.pumpListBox.Selected(i - 1) = checked(i - 1)
    Next i
    Let updating = False

    Let Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub pumpListBox_Change()
    If updating Then Exit Sub
    Dim i                   As Integer
    For i = 0 To maxChecks - 1
        If i < UBound(Me.pumpListBox.List) Then
            Let checked(i) = Me.pumpListBox.Selected(i)
        Else
            ''  remove options when reducing number of options
            Let checked(i) = False
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Public Property Get IsCancelled() As Boolean
    Let IsCancelled = cancelled
End Property

Private Sub OkButton_Click()
    Call Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    Call OnCancel
End Sub

Private Sub OnCancel()
    Let cancelled = True
    Call Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, answer was very useful. i tried using a combobox in the controls.add instead of an option button as you used in the answer above but it didnt work retuned a run time error specifying that object doesnt support the property or method. please how do i get around this as i want to use a combobox instead. thanks.